# Use my own rabbitTemplate with auto config connection factory Spring boot weird behaviour

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-boot

Hi I was trying to define my own rabbitTemplate with autoconfig connctionFactory of spring boot .
first i tried this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class MyConfiguration {

@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(){
  RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
  return template;
}
```

This was not working ...
So I have tried this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class MyConfiguration {
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
}
```

And its works perfectly can someone explain this ?

Comment: In the latter case Spring is beter able to figure out the order of dependencies (I suspect). The latter case might lead to eager instantiation of the template. But if you use auto config I think you can remove the `@EnableRabbit` as that is done by Spring Boot for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're injecting a bean reference in your configuration class. That bean reference is something that is provided by auto-config. We can't process that configuration class until those field references are wired. But, we're supposed to "parse" user configuration first (i.e. before auto-configuration kicks in).

This has nothing to do with Spring Boot by the way. You should avoid injecting dependencies like that, especially if these are only required by one `@Bean` declaration.

In other words, try as much as possible to avoid *cycles* in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation .B.T.W the idea to use autowiring came from boot code at RabbitAutoConfiguration class.

Comment: Inner classes are processed first, that's why it's legit. And it's part of auto-config so there is no cycle as in your case.